# Float is invalid field for Realm comparison

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have a very simple class in Realm:

```
@RealmClass
open class MethanolTest  (
    @PrimaryKey
    var substance: String = "",
    var value: Float = 0f,
    var _id: Long = 0
): RealmModel
```

Now I want to find a `value` that lies within some tolerance:

```
fun findSubstancesInMethanolTest(height : Float) =
        KRealm.select<MethanolTest> {
            it
                    .between("value",height-0.4,height+0.4)
        }
```

It compiles ok, but at runtime fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'value' in class 'MethanolTest' is of invalid type 'FLOAT'.
```

Well, it IS float! And this float can be queried in different places without this exception. It seems only comparison fails.

So what's wrong here?!

Comment: Have you tried 0.4f instead 9f 0.4

Comment: Tired. Anyway 0.4 === 0.4f

Answer (score 1):

In your case `height-0.4` results in **Double** type, that is what `between("value",height-0.4,height+0.4)` expects, if you take closer look you will see that `between` function require value to be double, because 2nd and 3rd params are double.
Simple example to prove this:

```
    private fun test(height: Float) {
        check(height, height - 0.4)
    }

    private fun check(f1: Float, f2: Float) {
    }
```

to keep it **Float** you need to make it `0.4F` (or less preferred `0.4.toFloat()`)

Comment: Well can't check it now. It seems it was a bug in Realm, as it fixed itself after upgrade to newest version.

Comment: Which version to which version?